# Qlikview- How to unqualify/concatenate many rows from many differents tables?

Tags: qlikview

I have multiple tables and each of them some fields are identical and several others are different. When I try to load them all at the same time the program "hangs" and I have to restart the application. It seems to me that the solution would be to use Qualify and unqualify or another script. I want all fields that are equal be concatenated. however there are tables that contain up to 229 columns.

I need from the key fields that I will be able to concatenate the information without losing the value of each field ..

How should I proceed to make all the same columms that are equal as a "KEY" without to need to list all of them?

this is how iam using the script..

```
LOAD Nome as Comarca, 
 Vara, 
 Entrancia, 
 Juiz, 
 Escrivao, 
 NomeMapa, 
 IdComarca, 
 Mes, 
 Ano, 
 MatJuiz, 
 IdVara, 
 IdEscrivao, 
 IdMapa, 
 DataFechamentoJuiz, 
 DataFechamentoEscrivao, 
 TitularRespondendo, 
 AndCausOrdiMesAnt, 
 AndCausOrdiAutu, 
 AndCausOrdiArqui, 
 AndCausOrdiAnda, 
 AndCausSumMesAnt, 
 AndCausSumAutu, 
 AndCausSumArqui, 
 AndCausSumAnda, 
 AndProcCautMesAnt, 
 AndProcCautAutu, 
 AndProcCautArqui, 
 AndProcCautAnda, 
 AndEmbarMesAnt, 
 AndEmbarAutu, 
 AndEmbarArqui, 
 AndEmbarAnda, 
 AndDemaisMesAnt, 
 AndDemaisAutu, 
 AndDemaisArqui, 
 AndDemaisAnda, 
 AndExecTotMesAnt, 
 AndExecTotAutu, 
 AndExecTotArqui, 
 AndExecTotAnda, 
 AndTituloExMesAnt, 
 AndTituloExAutu, 
 AndTituloExArqui, 
 AndTituloExAnda, 
 AndTituloJudMesAnt, 
 AndTituloJudAutu, 
 AndTituloJudArqui, 
 AndTituloJudAnda, 
 AndExecFiscMesAnt, 
 AndExecFiscAutu, 
 AndExecFiscArqui, 
 AndExecFiscAnda, 
 AndFedMesAnt, 
 AndFedAutu, 
 AndFedArqui, 
 AndFedAnda, 
 AndEstMesAnt, 
 AndEstAutu, 
 AndEstArqui, 
 AndEstAnda, 
 AndMuniMesAnt, 
 AndMuniAutu, 
 AndMuniArqui, 
 AndMuniAnda, 
 AndFalenMesAnt, 
 AndFalenAutu, 
 AndFalenArqui, 
 AndFalenAnda, 
 AndProcJuriMesAnt, 
 AndProcJuriAutu, 
 AndProcJuriArqui, 
 AndProcJuriAnda, 
 AndAcoPrevMesAnt, 
 AndAcoPrevAutu, 
 AndAcoPrevArqui, 
 AndAcoPrevAnda, 
 AndInciMesAnt, 
 AndInciAutu, 
 AndInciArqui, 
 AndInciAnda, 
 AndAcoIndeMesAnt, 
 AndAcoIndeAutu, 
 AndAcoIndeArqui, 
 AndAcoIndeAnda, 
 AndMandaMesAnt, 
 AndMandaAutu, 
 AndMandaArqui, 
 AndMandaAnda, 
 AndAcaCivMesAnt, 
 AndAcaCivAutu, 
 AndAcaCivArqui, 
 AndAcaCivAnda, 
 AndAcoTrabMesAnt, 
 AndAcoTrabAutu, 
 AndAcoTrabArqui, 
 AndAcoTrabAnda, 
 AndOutMesAnt, 
 AndOutAutu, 
 AndOutArqui, 
 AndOutAnda, 
 AndTotalMesAnt, 
 AndTotalAutu, 
 AndTotalArqui, 
 AndTotalAnda, 
 AndPrecMesAnt, 
 AndPrecAutu, 
 AndPrecArqui, 
 AndPrecAnda, 
 AndExecMesAnt, 
 AndExecAutu, 
 AndExecArqui, 
 AndExecAnda, 
 AndExecPenMesAnt, 
 AndExecPenAutu, 
 AndExecPenArqui, 
 AndExecPenAnda, 
 AndExecSuspMesAnt, 
 AndExecSuspAutu, 
 AndExecSuspArqui, 
 AndExecSuspAnda, 
 AndExecFisMesAnt, 
 AndExecFisAutu, 
 AndExecFisArqui, 
 AndExecFisAnda, 
 AndIncidProcJulg, 
 AndIncidProcExecJulg, 
 ProcConDist2005, 
 EmbExecDist2005, 
 ProcConDist2006MesAnt, 
 ProcConDist2006Julga, 
 ProcConDist2006Anda, 
 EmbaExec2006MesAnt, 
 EmbaExec2006Julga, 
 EmbaExec2006Anda, 
 MovProcConcPer, 
 MovProcConcl, 
 MovProcVistaMP, 
 MovProcCargaMP, 
 MovProcVistaPart, 
 MovProcOutTotal, 
 MovProcAudi, 
 MovProcCumpri, 
 MovProcDev, 
 MovProcPericia, 
 MovProcPubEdit, 
 MovProcProvEscriv, 
 MovProcSusp, 
 MovProcOutSitu, 
 MovProcArquiBaixa, 
 MovRecurInter, 
 MovRecurJulgAgravo, 
 MovRecurJulgapelacao, 
 MovRecurJulgtotal, 
 MovRecurProvAgravo, 
 MovRecurProvApelacao, 
 MovRecurProvTotal, 
 MovRecurInterFase, 
 MovRecurInterPend, 
 MovPrecNum, 
 MovPrecDataDist, 
 MovPrecDataUlt, 
 MovPrecDevTot, 
 MovPrecDevCit, 
 MovPrecDevOut, 
 RemTJMesAnt, 
 RemTJMesAtual, 
 RemTJDevolvTJ, 
 RemTJTotal, 
 RemOutTJMesAnt, 
 RemOutTJMesAtual, 
 RemOutTJDevolvTJ, 
 RemOutTJTotal, 
 RemOutComMesAnt, 
 RemOutComMesAtual, 
 RemOutComDevolvTJ, 
 RemOutComTotal, 
 RemRediOutMesAnt, 
 RemRediOutMesAtual, 
 RemRediOutDevolvTJ, 
 RemRediOutTotal, 
 RemOutrasInfo, 
 CustasProc, 
 CustasTaxaJudi, 
 CustasOutras, 
 AtosSentResMeritoTotal, 
 AtosSentResMeritoConhe, 
 AtosSentResMeritoCautelar, 
 AtosSentHomoTotal, 
 AtosSentHomoConhe, 
 AtosSentHomoCautelar, 
 AtosSentSemResolMeritoTotal, 
 AtosSentSemResolMeritoConhe, 
 AtosSentSemResolMeritoCautelar, 
 AtosMSentExecTotal, 
 AtosSentExecFiscal, 
 AtosMSentExecTitJud, 
 AtosMSentExecTitExt, 
 AtosDecisaoTotal, 
 AtosDecisaoLiminar, 
 AtosDecisaoOutras, 
 AtosDespProf, 
 AtosDespProfPlantao, 
 AtosAudRealizTotal, 
 AtosAudIntru, 
 AtosAudJulg, 
 AtosAudConcil, 
 AtosAudOutros, 
 AtosAudNRealiz, 
 AtosAudDesig, 
 AtosAcordoAudi, 
 AtosSentProfAudi, 
 AtosPesOuvAudi, 
 AtosDataAudiAfast, 
 AtosAutosConcSent, 
 AtosAutosConcPratica, 
 AtosAutosConcTotal, 
 AtosAutosConcSent100, 
 AtosAutosConcDiv100, 
 AtosDataConcAntiga, 
 AtosDecSusp, 
 AtosMandPriCivil, 
 AtosPresosCiveis, 
 AtosProcAntTramitNum, 
 AtosProcAntTramitData, 
 AtosProcAntTramitDUM, 
 AtosPrecAntTramitNum, 
 AtosPrecAntTramiData, 
 AtosPrecAntTramiDUM, 
 AtosPrecDevTotal, 
 AtosPrecDevCitacao, 
 AtosPrecDevOutras, 
 AtosInfTJ, 
 AtosOutrasAtividades, 
 Ferias, 
 MatSubstituicao, 
 MatAssinatura, 
 DataIniFerias, 
 DataFimFerias, 
 RemetOutraVara
```

FROM
[Z:\QLIKVIEW\Todos os Mapas\Area Cível.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is AreaCivil);

This a full list of rows of 1 of 16 tables..  some hows are equal in each table and some are different.

Comment: Hello Gorrpo, wellcome on SO. I think it would help if you add some example data. Only a few lines of each table. And please tell how many lines each table has. And you should add your Load script. Otherwise it will be hard to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Without knowing your details I would comment out all load statements but one and limit it to 10 Rows. If that loads well, add the next table and limit it to 10, too. If the result is okay continue that way. Otherwise you should rename fields while loading to avoid wrong syntetic keys.

Answer (score 0):

probably two different issues here. First, it hangs on you very likely because of memory issues - enable the detailed error log in the document settings so you can get some details during document reload.

Next, if i understand you correctly, you want to concatenate all 16 files to one table and these files have common columns and some different ones?

you have a few options here but I would recommend to manually rename common fields in your load script and also add columns you need to load from some other files to all other files but they will be blank if we are not on a specific file.

For example, 
file1 has columns key1,key2, c1, c2

and file2 has columns key1,key2, c1,c3

you can load them separately in the load script, but then you load file1, add blank column c3 and for file2, add blank column c2 - not to the actual files but to your load script statement.

you can also use forced concatenation by using CONCATENATE keyword before your load statement but I personally like to have control of QV load script myself.

Comment: I enabled the LOG. and the log showed that the loading did not complete. Program crashed right near the end. I use an AMD Phenom II x2 565 Processor 3.40 GHz with 8 GB RAM.

Comment: All 16 tables together there are over 2000 columns. Some columns are the same in all of them. There are some other similar and different columns between them. As they are over 2000 columns across 16 tables, I have no idea how to implement your suggestion. How would I use concatenate in the script? or other one like Qualify/Unqualify ?

Comment: basically you can do 16 statements LOAD * FROM table1 and before each load statement put keyword CONCATENATE. as result you will get one single table and columns with similar names and columns with different names. See this post http://www.qlikfix.com/2010/12/09/merging-tables-concatenation/